# В чем сложность удаления элемента из хеш-таблицы с открытой адресацией

Tags: c++, алгоритм, data-structures

Допустим у нас есть хеш-таблица. Коллизии разрешаются с помощью открытой адресации(линейное пробирование). Какие будут сложности при удалении элемента?

Comment: ксли мне память не изменяет, с удалением сложности нет, сложности будут при последующем поиске

Comment: Нужно передвинуть (почти) все элементы, хранящиеся в массиве, начиная с удаляемого, до следующей "пустышки", причем их взаимный порядок, возможно, изменится. Ничего сложного, но есть место для ошибок.